# Can we prove heron's formula by using differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

How can we use methods of differential geometry to prove heron's formula (which is about  the area of triangle) ?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "analytic geometry" and are you looking for something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Generalizations)?

Comment: i know its proof using geometry i want to know its proof using differential geometry